# Rails Admin: No edit, show, or delete buttons for Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

Using rails_admin for a very basic Rails 4 application.

However, whenever I open up the dashboard (mounted at '/admin'), I do not see the edit, show, or delete link buttons for each of my records.

Interestingly, if I manually go to the show or edit routes (i.e. /admin/*products*/1 or /admin/*products*/1/edit) the page shows up just fine and works as expected.

Is there a configuration to turn these links on?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In your `config/initilizers/rails_admin.rb` there is this config block? https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Actions#default

Comment: I added that config block to my rails_admin initializer, restarted the server, and revisited the page. I still don't see any links :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out!

It turned out to be a conflict with Bootstrap/FontAwesome between my application and rails_admin.

I was using Bootstrap 3 along with FontAwesome 4 whereas the version of rails_admin I'm using (0.5.0) was using Bootstrap 2 with FontAwesome 3.

Since rails_admin was meant to use the old FontAwesome, it was using the old-style syntax (e.g. 'icon icon-pencil') instead of the new-style (e.g. 'fa fa-pencil'). Because of this, the icons were not showing up.

I resolved this by removing FontAwesome 4 from my app (I wasn't using it much anyway) and letting rails_admin use the version of FontAwesome is was bundled with.